# ROS launch dependency checker

Tags: ros, roslaunch, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a tool that can be used to check that launch dependencies and other non-compile time dependencies are met.  I always have the problem where I fail to make all the packages that are required for a launch file, because the package isn't referenced in the manifest/package.xml.  If the package isn't referenced, rosmake will work correctly but calling the launch file will not.  This is especially problematic for releases.  Ideally a released package would have all dependencies, build, launch, plugins, anything else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56000/ros-launch-dependency-checker/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like to include [rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check()](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_add_roslaunch_check) in my unit tests.

It statically checks that the specified launch files only use packages with an explicit dependency.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3